# How to add beacons to the app from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I have created an app using beacons and I've configured their UUID, Major values in the app itself and everything is working fine. And it is doing background monitoring also.

Once the app ranges a beacon, the app is sending the beacon UUID, Major, Minor and Proximity Level information to server using web service and in response it is getting the product details to show to the user.

But my question is how to add beacon details from a web service. So that I do not need to update my app in app store every time i add a new beacon in the store.

How the background monitoring can be done if beacon details are not in the app? And do we need to call the beacon details web service every time the app opens?

I am not getting any idea how to achieve that. I am new to beacon functionality.

This is my present code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSUUID *beaconUUID1 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion1 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID1 major:2 identifier:@"Identifier1"];
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID1 major:3 identifier:@"Identifier2"];

    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            NSLog(@"Authorized Always");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
            NSLog(@"Authorized when in use");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"Denied");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"Not determined");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"Restricted");
            break;        
        default:
            break;
    }

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion1];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion1];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion2];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion2];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CBCentralManager* testBluetooth = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil queue: nil];

}
```

Further information:-
I am using Estimote beacons but not their SDK. I'm using Only Core Location Framework.

Can anyone give a clear picture on how to implement dynamic beacon details from server?

Comment: download the beacon informations from server and then start the region monitoring when you're done with download... or what do you mean?

Comment: You don't have to do that in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, you can do it wherever you want. So you can download the beacons information and start the monitoring when you have all the beacons.

Comment: thanks guys. i will try your solutions. Earlier i thought i have to do that only in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions... but now i will write the code in different method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this yourself, here are the basic steps:

1. Make an asynchronous web service call to fetch the configuration information from the server in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` *before* you set up any beacon monitoring.
2. When you get a successful callback from the web service, parse the response, set up your `CLBeaconRegions` based on what it returns, and start monitoring and ranging.
3. (Optional) You may wish to implement persistent storage (e.g. to sharedPreferences) of these regions, and store them after a successful web service call.  That way, if you get a failure in contacting the web service, you can simply load the regions back from persistent storage and use the last known copy.

My company has a product called [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com/) that does all of this for you (and more), so if you are interested in using a framework, it may be easier than rolling your own.

Comment: Why not send a push notification to app from server ?